# How to correctly configure Apache tomcat 9 within eclipse because I have the necessary jar files (mail.jar and activation.jar)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, soap, tomcat9

For some reason on my Mac along with Windows I'm stuck at the same place as far as configuring my Apache Tomcat server within eclipse. I'm creating a small SOAP service but I keep receiving this error when I start the server 'WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.' I've tried many of the old solutions on the internet as far as editing config files and making sure those jars are added in the classpath. Not sure if I need to specifically place those jar files somewhere within my tomcat directory (which I tried but didn't work) or place them specifically in my eclipse web-inf/lib folder (which I tried but didnt work)

[image: jar files saved in web-inf/lib of my eclipse workspace]

[image: class path picture showing jars uploaded]

Not really sure what else do, could those who provide assist give other solutions other than the common ones found on the internet.

---

And another side question is how to i access localhost after the server is running, it initially used to load on the default browser but now it doesn't and doesn't let me type in https://localhost:8443 picture attached

[image: localhost not loading resource]

Stack:
java version "1.8.0_333"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_333-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.333-b02, mixed mode)
Apache Tomcat Server 9.0.62
Windows 10/MacOs Monterey
Eclipse

Comment: If those jar files are particular to your web app, they should be in WEB-INF/lib and that *should* work at web app runtime. You can check which ports are listening with `netstat`

Comment: You're sure Tomcat is being run with Java 1.8? Are those messages about your application, or from Tomcat about itself? Also, unless you deployed the application that comes in the webapps/ROOT folder of the Tomcat zip/tar, you won't see anything at the root of the server.

Comment: You might want to use the [*Jakarta SOAP with Attachments*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/soap-attachments/) specification. Then, instead of Tomcat, deploy to an app server that includes an implementation of that spec. One such app server is [TomEE](https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-9.0/docs/comparison.html#specifications), an extension of Tomcat that adds support for several of the Java EE/Jakarta EE specs. With this approach, you do not bundle either the API nor the implementation of that SOAP spec with your app.

Comment: yes i'm 100% sure java -version confirms it but this is coming directly from the console in eclipse, my main question is do I need those 2 jars specifically to create a soap service to post http requests @nitind